# Show on hover, hide on click with jQuery

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I've been trying some basic move in jQuery but I'm a beginner in it.
How do achieve that?

Here is my code so far :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    // show/hide
    jQuery('#div').hide(); //hide at the beginning

    jQuery('#hover').hover(function () {
        jQuery("#div").show(400);
        jQuery('#hover').text('-');
        jQuery('#hover').addClass('click');
        jQuery('.click').height('auto');
        jQuery('.click').width('auto');
        jQuery('.click').css("font-size", "1em");
    }), jQuery("#div").hover(function () {
        //nothing on hover over
    }, function () {
        //hide on hover out
    });
});
```

My HTML markup is the following :

```
<a id="hover" href="javascript:;">Hide</a>
<div id="div">test</div>
```

I got the feeling I'm in the wrong way to do it.
Can you help me?

Comment: clicking an element requires hovering over it . ya know !

Comment: Yes but I'm trying to replace the original button maybe hide it and display some minimize icon. How to do that even with 2 button?

Comment: and what do you want `#hover` to do after it is hovered and `#div` is hidden? do you want it to show while hovering and then hide when not hovering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax seems a little off, as you've declared two `hover` functions and don't even have a click handler?

Try this:

```
$('#hover')
    .mouseenter(function() {
        $('#div').show();
    })
    .click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#div').hide();
    });
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/7ve9D/)

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out what you are going for. I modified your dom and used classes to make it more flexible as this looks like something you might have multiple of, if not you can switch back to id's.

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8QufW/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".div").hide(); //hide at the beginning

    jQuery('.hover').hover(function () {
        jQuery(this).siblings(".div").show(400);
    });
    jQuery(".div").on("mouseout", function () {
        jQuery(this).hide();
    });
});
```

---

Here is another option using a click on a text that changes (open/close):

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8QufW/2/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".div").hide(); //hide at the beginning

    function hideDiv(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery(this).text('open')
            .click(showDiv)
            .siblings(".div").hide(400)
    }

    function showDiv(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery(this).text('close')
            .click(hideDiv)
            .siblings(".div").show(400)
    }
    jQuery('.hover').click(showDiv);
});
```